# How to covert Timestap 'String' to Date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

In javascript, I have a timestamp value as a string. How to get Date from the same.

I know we can get a date from timestamp like below:

`console.log(new Date(1535704620000));
 Fri Aug 31 2018 14:07:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

But in my case, I want to get the value from the Timestamp value in the string as below:

```
console.log(new Date('1535704620000'));
Invalid Date
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ...just turn the string into a number first?

Comment: Thank you for the quick help!!! @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to turn the string passed into the Date constructor into a number, which can be done with the *unary plus operator*:

```
  new Date(+'1535704620000')
```